# I'm using views-blocks to render a drupal template. I need to let an end-user select the item. How do I do that?

Tags: drupal

I'm rendering a page in Drupal that looks like this: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS9DO.jpg) Essentially this is rendered by using blocks and views: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOGry.png)

I would like to be add end-user functionality whereby a content user can click on any of the grid items and select the content that goes into that grid item. A typical flow might be:
- Click on edit next to the grid item
- A modal opens up
- User sees list of specific content 
- User selects an item and the modal closes
- Selected item now shows up in the grid item.

I would like to be able to do this without any custom development. Is there any module out there that can do this?

Comment: Is this Drupal 7?

Comment: Yes it is -- Drupal 7

Comment: Panels does provide some in-place editing functionality. You may be able to output the Views row as a panel. I don't know that you'll get everything you want without custom development. Drupal 8 core has better integration with this, so-called Quick Edit functionality.